# Set marker in street view and clear them

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-street-view

it's possible to show and hide a marker in street view?

I'm only able to add marker in panorama with the classic

```
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: posizione,
                    icon: 'Azure.png',   
                    map: myPano,    
                    title: myMarker[0]
                    });
```

but doing so i'm not able to remove any of them...

Please help!

Comment: Please provide a [complete (preferably simple) example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.  How are you trying to remove the markers?  What javascript errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to remove the marker would be:

```
marker.setMap(null);
marker = null;
```

Whether or not this is the correct solution here depends largely on your specific implementation.